# How to return an Element to its base in StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, uiview, storyboard, swift2

I made a UIView with some elements in it in StoryBoard (I used autoLayout).
After that, I manipulated it programmatically (change sizes, move elements, etc.). How can I return the UIView to its base in StoryBoard after the user taps on UIButton? Is there any code that can return an element to its base? I have tried this:

```
myView.reloadInputViews()
```

But it didn't work. I also tried to make an instance of the UIView before I manipulated. That also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without re-instantiating the corresponding view controller from the storyboard.

You should save all parameters, you want to restore in a variable in the view controller. Then you can set them back to the view when the button is tapped.

Edit: For example like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let initialFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 30, height: 40)
    @IBOutlet weak var mySubView: UIView!        

    func myButtonAction() {
        mySubView.frame = initialFrame
    }
}
```

Comment: can you explain more please , i don't get it